# Is the Universal Property Alone Enough to Use Tensor Products?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

I'm reading Atiyah-Macdonald's *Introduction to Commutative Algebra*, and I'm interested in the remark that the authors make after detailing the construction of the tensor product of modules on p. 25:

> We shall never again need to use the construction of the tensor product given in (2.12), and the reader may safely forget it if he prefers. What is essential to keep in mind is the defining property of the tensor product.

This makes sense to me, since we always seem to create maps out of $M \otimes N$ by starting with a bilinear map from $M \times N$ and using the universal property. But sometimes, especially when verifying injectivity and surjectivity of the induced map, we have to use the fact that $M \otimes N$ is generated by pure tensors of the form $x \otimes y$. Taking the above remark literally, we should be able to prove this fact without resorting to the construction of $M \otimes N$ at all, but I can't figure out how this can be done with the universal property alone. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Do you have a particular example of such a proof in mind?

Comment: @Thorgott Sure - to prove there exists an isomorphism $R \otimes M \to M$, where $R$ is the base ring, we use the universal property to induce a map $\phi : a \otimes m \mapsto am$. To show it's bijective, we look at the map $\psi : m \mapsto 1 \otimes m$ and verifying that $\psi \circ \phi = id$ requires the fact that pure tensors generate $R \otimes M$.

Comment: @Nick: you can prove this using just the universal property, actually.

Comment: @Nick: in more detail, by the universal property maps $R \otimes M \to N$ correspond to $R$-bilinear maps $R \times M \to N$. But you can check that such bilinear maps are the same thing as just linear maps $M \to N$ so you're done by the Yoneda lemma. The isomorphism itself is the map $R \otimes M \to M$ corresponding to scalar multiplication $R \times M \to M$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the universal bilinear map

$$\beta: M \times N \rightarrow M \otimes N.$$

The elementary tensor $m \otimes n$ is just $\beta(m, n)$. Let therefore $T$ denote the subgroup/submodule (it's the same thing in this case) of $M \otimes N$ generated by the image of $\beta$. Clearly $\beta$ "corestricts" to the bilinear map $$M \times N \rightarrow T.$$

Now one just observes that $T$ itself satisfies the universal property defining $M \otimes N$. The point is that any bilinear map $\alpha: M\times N \rightarrow A$ induces uniquely a linear map $M\otimes N \rightarrow A,$ and hence by restriction also $T \rightarrow A$, through which $\alpha$ factors (and uniqueness of such map is again clear). That checks the universal property for $T$. It then follows that $T=M\otimes N$.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks!

Comment: Actually on second thought, I'm having trouble verifying that the induced map $T \to A$ is unique. Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: @NickA. That part, funnily enough, actually *uses* the fact that the image of $\beta: M\times N \rightarrow T$ generates $T$: $\beta(m, n)$ needs to be sent to $\alpha(m, n)$, so the only candidate for the factorization is already determined on a generating set.

Comment: Right of course, makes sense now.